# Importing Lua NodeMCU to IntelliJ for autocomplete?

Tags: intellij-idea, lua, nodemcu

How can I import the [NodeMCU Wifi documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/wifi/) in IntelliJ so I can get good autocomplete functionality?

Or should I use another IDE/Text editor for this?

Comment: Any further feedback needed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, sorry. There is no IDE/editor that provides NodeMCU autocomplete because there is none that knows our API. We were discussing an approach in https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1667 a (long) while ago.